# Manage looping on txt file with AppleScript

Tags: list, loops, automation, applescript, text-files

I have a text file that looks like this: screenshot below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqKzS.png

Each item has this format:
ID<>Text
~~
ID<>Text
~~
I want to fetch the ID in an INT to be used later. And the Text in a String to be used later.
I looped over the file many times using delimiters "<>" & "~~". However, I fail each time with a different script error.
 
first I faced difficulties because the file contains a lot of newlines throughout the "Text". 
Also, the text sometimes contains an English paragraph followed by an Arabic paragraph, as showed in the Screenshot.

 **The ID as highlighted should be {9031} 
and the Text should be 
{N/M06"El Patio.......

......

....

....

....

*Arabic Text.....*}**
Can someone help me with the correct script to loop over this text file and fetch each ID followed by its text to be used in a DataEntry process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose I recommend to install [Satimage sax 3.7.0](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/downloads/downloads_companion_osaxen.html)

The benefit is to find text with regular expression.

Then you easily filter the text with `find text`

```
set theText to read file "HD:Path:to:text.txt" as «class utf8» -- replace the HFS path with the actual path
set theResult to {}
set matches to find text "\\d{1,4}<>.*" in theText with regexp and all occurrences
repeat with aMatch in matches
    tell aMatch's matchResult
        set end of theResult to {text 1 thru 4, text 7 thru -1}
    end tell
end repeat
```

`find text` returns a record:

> `matchLen`: length of the match
>   `matchPos`: offset of the match (0 is the first character!)
>   `matchResult`: the matching string (possibly formatted according to the "using" parameter)

The result of the script in variable `theResult` is a list of lists containing the `id` and the `text`. The `text` starts after the `<>` but you might cut more characters.

**Edit:**

It seems that the regex can't parse this text (or my regex knowledge is too bad).

This is a pure AppleScript version without the Scripting Addition.

```
set theText to read file ((path to desktop as text) & "description.txt") as «class utf8» -- replace the HFS path with the actual path
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, ("~~" & linefeed)}
set theMatches to text items of theText
set text item delimiters to TID
set theResult to {}
repeat with aMatch in theMatches
    if length of aMatch > 1 then
        tell aMatch
            set end of theResult to {text 1 thru 4, text 7 thru -1}
        end tell
    end if
end repeat
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Vadian. I had a small question. After I have done this the "text" shows only the first line, and doesnt show the rest of the text till "~~". Can you guide me on how to read the bunch of lines into "text" until the character that splits one entry from the next one "~~". Here is the screenshot of an example of one entry: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AqKzS.png

Comment: Is the text UTF8 encoded? I tested the script with sample text according to your screen shot.

Comment: I actually dont know if it is UTF8 encoded. but the script worked fine but it only fetches some text into 'text' and not all text till "~~". For the highlighted example I have sent in the screenshot, it fetched in 'text' until the word "odor"

Comment: Can you upload the text file somewhere?

Comment: Thanks so much for this! This works great and I very much appreciate the help you have offered. You have been very helpful!!

Comment: Hello Vadian, I had an issue completing the full script, and cant find answers anywhere. Could you please help me? http://stackoverflow.com/q/38442713/6544702

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with JavaScript.